# Flutter how to set container background as transparent color

Tags: dart, flutter, android-alertdialog

[I found this question but doesn't work for me.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51837717/make-container-background-as-transparent)

I also play with `Opacity` widget and *decoration* color of `Container`. But didn't find solution It always display **white** background color when I set it transparent.

Look at below image, Instead of red color it should be transparent.

[image]

Below are my code:

```
_showAlertDialog(String strTitle, String strDetails) {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            content: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Opacity(
                  opacity: 1, // Also tried to set 0
                  child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 0, 0, 0.5) // I played with different colors code for get transparency of color but Alway display White. 
                    ),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          height: 50,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10, top: 2),
                          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                          child: Center(
                            child: Text(
                              strTitle,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                  fontSize: 14),
                              maxLines: 2,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Flexible(
                          child: Container(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                            child: SingleChildScrollView(
                              child: Text(
                                strDetails,
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87, fontSize: 12, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                    top: 0,
                    right: 0,
                    child:
                    Container(
                      height: 24,
                      width: 24,
                      child: DecoratedBox(
                        child: IconButton(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                            icon: Icon(Icons.close, color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor, size: 18,), onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.of(context).pop();
                        }),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                )
              ],
            ),
          );
        });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The `AlertDialog` Widget has a `backgroundColor` property , just set it to transparent.

```
  AlertDialog(
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
```

And remove the `BoxDecoration`

**Update**
Looks like `backgroundColor` is not available on Flutter 1.0.0 yet.
(I'm on dev channel)

stable: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/stable/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/dialog.dart

dev: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/dev/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/dialog.dart

Checking the source code of Dialog , I found it was using the `dialogBackgroundColor` from theme. Try this easy way:

```
  showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return Theme(
              data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(dialogBackgroundColor: Colors.transparent),
              child: AlertDialog(
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                content: Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      color: Colors.white,
                      ...
```

Comment: I can't set `backgroundColor: Colors.transparent`. It gives me error.

Comment: hmm what version of Flutter do you have?

Comment: its Flutter 1.0.0 BTW https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/AlertDialog-class.html **AlertDialog** it self has not this type of property

Comment: yes, you are right, looks like is not available in that version yet.

Comment: By copy paste **class MyAlertDialog** I got so many error. Have you tried?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186446/discussion-between-ipatel-and-diegoveloper).

Answer (score 14):

**You can achieve this simply with this:**

```
...
   color: Colors.red.withOpacity(0),
                            ...
```

you can specify how much opacity you want by using decimal value from 0 to 1, 0 being fully transparent while 1 being fully opaque .

Answer (score 12):

You can also do as below

```
backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(r, g, b, 0)
```

Comment: What is r, g and b variables?

Comment: R = Red, G = green, B = Blue e.g backgroundColor: Color.fromRBGO(255, 0, 0, 1). This is make the background color to Red with Opacity set as 1 or no opacity

Answer (score 0):

If looking for clear background, use:

```
backgroundColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.0),
```