# Flutter Web background with opacity

Tags: flutter, web

I want page that has opacitiy on its background, so the user can see previous page's layout even in the second page. I try to use `showDialog()`, but it wasn't the answer, since it does not have routename. I will attach the picture that I want. Please help.

[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHlDK.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can check this answer on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54123097/flutter-how-to-set-container-background-as-transparent-color), is similar.
Or do it in a different way and use [Stack](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) and [Opacity](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Opacity-class.html) widgets to achieve this.